# Clang++ undefined reference errors with GMock

Tags: c++, clang++, googlemock

I did a dist-upgrade yesterday and now I'm getting undefined reference errors when I compile tests using GMock and clang++;  it is working fine with g++ though.
GTest and GMock are compiled from source and installed with Cmake.

I was wondering if anyone knows why it isn't linking properly?

I'm compiling with:

```
clang++-3.7 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c++11 -Wshadow a.cpp -o a.out -lgtest -lgmock -pthread
```

I'm gettting these errors:

```
/tmp/a-bb74fa.o: In function `testing::internal::FunctionMockerBase<int ()>::DescribeDefaultActionTo(std::tuple<> const&, std::ostream*) const':
a.cpp:(.text._ZNK7testing8internal18FunctionMockerBaseIFivEE23DescribeDefaultActionToERKSt5tupleIJEEPSo[_ZNK7testing8internal18FunctionMockerBaseIFivEE23DescribeDefaultActionToERKSt5tupleIJEEPSo]+0x8e): undefined reference to `testing::internal::FormatFileLocation(char const*, int)'
/tmp/a-bb74fa.o: In function `testing::internal::ExpectationBase::DescribeLocationTo(std::ostream*) const':
a.cpp:(.text._ZNK7testing8internal15ExpectationBase18DescribeLocationToEPSo[_ZNK7testing8internal15ExpectationBase18DescribeLocationToEPSo]+0x43): undefined reference to `testing::internal::FormatFileLocation(char const*, int)'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

make: *** [a.out] Error 1

The source code:

```
#include<gtest/gtest.h>
#include<gmock/gmock.h>
#include <iostream>

class printable{
    public:
        virtual int print() = 0;
};

class A{
    public:
        A( printable* b ) :
            obj( b )
        {}
        int doit(){return obj->print();}
    private:
        printable* obj;
};

class MockPrintable : public printable{
    public:
        MOCK_METHOD0( print, int() );
};

TEST( test, returnStuff ){
    MockPrintable b;
    A a( &b );
    EXPECT_CALL( b, print() )
    .WillOnce( testing::Return( 1 ) )
    .WillOnce( testing::Return( 2 ) )
    .WillOnce( testing::Return( 3 ) );
    EXPECT_EQ( 1,a.doit() );
    EXPECT_EQ( 2,a.doit() );
    EXPECT_EQ( 3,a.doit() );
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] ){
    ::testing::InitGoogleMock( &argc, argv );
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

#### edit:

I've narrowed the problem down somewhat to `libgcc-5-dev` and `libstdc++-5-dev`
packages.

`libstdc++-5-dev` causes this error:

```
/usr/local/include/gtest/gtest.h:54:10: fatal error: 'limits' file not found
#include <limits>
```

`libstdc++-5-dev` causes a lot of **undefined reference** errors relating to
gmock.

I can't seem to link against older versions using `-l` and `-L`.  Searching
around turns up results advising against trying to statically link against these
and to use older versions of the compiler instead.  But, the compiler
dependencies now requires the same `*-5-dev` packages according to apt-get.

You can prevent apt-get from using these package by inserting this into
`/etc/apt/preferences:`

```
Package: libgcc-5-dev
Pin: release *
Pin-Priority: -1

Package: libstdc++-5-dev
Pin: release *
Pin-Priority: -1
```

and just `dist-upgrade` from there, but it prevents g++, clang and other things
from updating so it isn't worth it; `apt-get` suggests removing `clang` as part
of `dist-upgrade` anyhow.

Lastly, I tried to use the precompiled-binary for clang-3.8 from their website but it gave me a
humongous wall of undefined reference to std::< everything >.  I did get a
hello world program to compile though so it can at least find `std::cout` and
`std::endl`.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the include paths. The package you mention does not actually "cause" the error. In fact it is needed as it provides the standard C++ header files (under ```/usr/include/c++/...```).

Comment: I tried using `-I/usr/local/include` (and more specifically with  .../include/gmock and .../include/gtest) but that didn't change anything.

Comment: ```/usr/local/include``` or ```/usr/include```, where did you install gmock and gtest?

Comment: `/usr/local/include/gmock` and `/usr/local/include/gtest` the `.../` was meant to signify `-I/usr/local`.

Comment: Have you recompiled your gmock and gtest libraries after the dist upgrade? Maybe the binaries are referencing wrong paths (which changed due to the upgrade to newer libstdc++).

Comment: Recompiling did actually solve the problem as it turns out. Sadly, it doesn't seem to be compatible with the other compiler.  If I want to use g++ I have to compile with g++ and likewise with clang++. Ultimately it seems that the solution is to keep two copies of the library - one for clang and one for g++ :(

Comment: @user821596: But that's always been the case. You can't mix toolchains, in general.

Comment: I could actually switch freely between them prior to the upgrade though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are victim of the ABI change introduced with libstdc++ in v5. They had to change the implementation of `std::string`, because C++11 mandates a particular implementation while was not the case before. That lead to changes in symbol names. The problem is specific to migrating from pre-v5 libstdc++ (gcc) to v5 or higher and should therefore not happen again.

Comment: The undefined errors mentioned two subroutines: DecribeDefaultActionTo and **FormatFileLocation**.  The [former calls the latter: line 1644](https://github.com/google/googlemock/blob/master/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-spec-builders.h) and the latter **returns std::string** ([according to a testcase: line 899](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/test/gmock-spec-builders_test.cc)).
...

Comment: According to [this article](http://allanmcrae.com/2015/06/the-case-of-gcc-5-1-and-the-two-c-abis/) in the second last paragraph, it states that there would be issues with **not recognizing std::string return types when compiling with clang** since it doesn't recognize the *abic++11* symbol.
So it checks out :)